# How to create a custom page with Codeigniter, not as controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a website which is built on Codeigniter and I want to create some pages with information like terms or privacy, their address should be:

```
http://domain.com/terms
http://domain.com/privacy
```

My question is: should I create for each page a controller? In CMS for example, if I add a page it has to create a 'pysical' page on the server (CMS which is built on Codeigniter)?

Comment: No, you should create one contoller that will take the page id/name  from a url parameter

Comment: Then it'll be `http://domain.com/page/terms` for example (with the controller page). it is not good. Am I wrong? Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to use routing to remove "page" from the URL.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For static pages like a Privacy Policy or Terms of Service page where they don't really fit under any other controller I usually create a "content" controller that looks something like this:

```
class Content extends CI_Controller {

    public function privacy_policy()
    {
        $this->load->view('privacy_policy');
    }

    public function terms_of_service()
    {
        $this->load->view('terms_of_service');
    }

}
```

Then I add some [routes](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) to remove "content" from the URL:

```
$route['privacy-policy']   = 'content/privacy_policy';
$route['terms-of-service'] = 'content/terms_of_service';
```

That way you don't need to create a new controller for each page and you can keep your static pages organized in a single spot.

Comment: Cool, thank you. But how can I block users who enter via content/terms-of-service? (I mean `http://domain.com/content/terms-of-service`) There is a way from the framework? or I should do manually redirect 301 with htaccess?

Comment: Check the documentation: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#private

Answer (score 0):

Something I do is make your policy statements as a DL, DT, DD. hide the DD with jquery, show the DD then on a click to the DT. Then have the DD popup as a modal

The entire thing is contained in the footer. No need for anything to do with the controller